# Code for PID for EV3-g

Tags: mindstorms, ev3, ev3-g

I want to use [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller) for my Ev3. I used PID for NXT-G before, but I have never used EV3-G before and don't know how to get PID. Could someone please post a screen shot of the code or upload the file?

Comment: Not clear whether "I used PID for NXT-G" means you wrote a PID in NXT-G for use on an NXT, or you bought a 3rd party PID control for use with an NXT.  Let's assume you want to write the program.  A starting point is: http://e-fisica.fc.up.pt/edicoes/8a-edicao/projectos/robo-sensorizado-com-lego-mindstorms/documentacao/PID%20Controller%20For%20Lego%20Mindstorms%20Robots.pdf (from a google search for "PID NXT").

Answer (score 3):

This is EV3-G code for a PID based on [PID Controller for Lego Mindstorms Robots by J Sluka](http://www.inpharmix.com/jps/PID_Controller_For_Lego_Mindstorms_Robots.html).  It uses the steering parameter of the Move block instead of power levels of the Motor block.  The interesting parts are setting the Kp, Ki, and Kd values.

[image]

Comment: i understand that code. But how to make robot go straight for 5 rotations for example. without waiting between rotations ? thanks

Comment: Good point, this example runs forever. One way to implement stopping after 5 rotations, would be to replace the infinite loop with a loop that runs until the left motor + right motor   > 10 rotations. Obviously, that would be less than ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The best documentation I have found for PID is "A PID Controller For Lego Mindstorms Robots" by J. Sluka

J. Sluka 
Send me an email at:
Lego at InPharmix dot com

It is written for the NXT and needs to be updated for the EV3.  But it has really helped me out.  I am working on a maze solver and used PID to follow the wall.  I prefer to program the EV3 in python and have included the code here.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# so this script/program can be run from Brickman

from ev3dev.ev3 import *
from time import sleep

import ev3dev.ev3 as ev3

print('Auto Driver TubeBotEZ.py')
# File EV3 Python TubeBot.py
ev3.Sound.speak('python Tube Robot easy 2').wait()

LeftWheel = LargeMotor('outA')
RightWheel = LargeMotor('outB')
ir = InfraredSensor()
# assert ir.connected, "Connect a single infrared sensor to any sensor port"

ts = TouchSensor()
# assert ts.connected, "Connect a touch sensor to any port"
# can have 2 statements on same line if use semi colon

# Put the infrared sensor into proximity mode.
ir.mode = 'IR-PROX'

DelayTime = 0
Target = 10
Error = 0
Integral = 0
Derivative = 0
LastError = 0
Kp = 3
Ki = 0
Kd = 0
PID = 1
Time = 400
LeftPower = 1
RightPower = 1
MaxTurnPower = 200
Iteration = 0
Distance = 0
SpeedFactor = 300
y = 0
Speed = 100
OldDistance = 1000
DistanceL = 1
DistanceR = 2

Beginning = '{:3d}        Start                        Left Distance {:>4.0f}     Right Distance {:>4.0f}'.format(Iteration, DistanceL, DistanceR)
Ending = '        LeftPower {:>5.0f}    RightPower {:>5.0f}'.format(
    LeftPower, RightPower)
print(Beginning, Ending)

#ev3.Sound.speak('Start').wait()
sleep(DelayTime)
Battery = True
#Sound.speak('Point 1')
while Battery:
    Leds.all_off()
#    Leds.set_color(Leds.UP, Leds.GREEN)
#    Leds.set_color(Leds.DOWN, Leds.GREEN)
    Leds.set_color(Leds.LEFT, Leds.GREEN)
    Leds.set_color(Leds.RIGHT, Leds.GREEN)
    # Phase 1
    if True:

#        Sound.speak('SQUARE WALL')
        sleep(DelayTime)
        DistanceL = ir.value()
        LeftWheel.run_to_rel_pos(position_sp=20, speed_sp=900, stop_action="hold")
        RightWheel.run_to_rel_pos(position_sp=-20, speed_sp=900, stop_action="hold")
        #sleep(DelayTime)   # Give the motor time to move
        #LeftWheel.stop()
        LeftWheel.wait_while('running')
        RightWheel.wait_while('running')
        #sleep(1)
        DistanceR = ir.value()
        if DistanceL != DistanceR:
            if DistanceL < DistanceR:
                while DistanceL < DistanceR:
#                    print('in Left loop')

#                    Sound.speak('Left').wait()
                    sleep(DelayTime)   # Give the motor time to move
                    DistanceR = ir.value()
                    LeftWheel.run_to_rel_pos(position_sp=-20, speed_sp=900, stop_action="hold")
                    RightWheel.run_to_rel_pos(position_sp=20, speed_sp=900, stop_action="hold")
                    sleep(DelayTime)   # Give the motor time to move
                    LeftWheel.stop()
                    LeftWheel.wait_while('running')
                    sleep(DelayTime)
                    DistanceL = ir.value()
                    Iteration += 1
                    Beginning = '{:3d}      Left      in                    Left Distance {:>4.0f}     Right Distance {:>4.0f}'.format(Iteration, DistanceL, DistanceR)
                    Ending = '        LeftPower {:>5.0f}    RightPower {:>5.0f}'.format(
                        LeftPower, RightPower)
                    print(Beginning, Ending)
#                ev3.Sound.speak('Re set Right').wait()
                LeftWheel.run_to_rel_pos(position_sp=20, speed_sp=900, stop_action="hold")
                RightWheel.run_to_rel_pos(position_sp=-20, speed_sp=900, stop_action="hold")
                sleep(DelayTime)   # Give the motor time to move
                LeftWheel.stop()
                LeftWheel.wait_while('running')
                sleep(DelayTime)
                Iteration += 1
                Beginning = '{:3d}       Left out                     Left Distance {:>4.0f}     Right Distance {:>4.0f}'.format(Iteration, DistanceL, DistanceR)
                Ending = '        LeftPower {:>5.0f}    RightPower {:>5.0f}'.format(
                    LeftPower, RightPower)
                print(Beginning, Ending)
                Sound.beep()
            else:
                while DistanceR < DistanceL:
#                    print('in while close loop')

#                    ev3.Sound.speak('Right').wait()
                    sleep(DelayTime)
                    DistanceL = ir.value()
                    LeftWheel.run_to_rel_pos(position_sp=20, speed_sp=900, stop_action="hold")
                    RightWheel.run_to_rel_pos(position_sp=-20, speed_sp=900, stop_action="hold")
                    sleep(DelayTime)  # Give the motor time to move
                    LeftWheel.stop()
                    LeftWheel.wait_while('running')
                    sleep(DelayTime)
                    DistanceR = ir.value()
                    Iteration += 1
                    Beginning = '{:3d}          Right   in                   Left Distance {:>4.0f}     Right Distance {:>4.0f}'.format(Iteration, DistanceL, DistanceR)
                    Ending = '        LeftPower {:>5.0f}    RightPower {:>5.0f}'.format(
                        LeftPower, RightPower)
                    print(Beginning, Ending)

#                ev3.Sound.speak('Reset Left').wait()
                LeftWheel.run_to_rel_pos(position_sp=-30, speed_sp=900, stop_action="hold")
                RightWheel.run_to_rel_pos(position_sp=30, speed_sp=900, stop_action="hold")
                sleep(DelayTime)  # Give the motor time to move
                LeftWheel.stop()
                LeftWheel.wait_while('running')
                sleep(DelayTime)
                Iteration += 1
                Beginning = '{:3d}          Right   in       out            Left Distance {:>4.0f}     Right Distance {:>4.0f}'.format(Iteration, DistanceL, DistanceR)
                Ending = '        LeftPower {:>5.0f}    RightPower {:>5.0f}'.format(
                    LeftPower, RightPower)
                print(Beginning, Ending)

                Sound.beep()

        Beginning = '{:3d}       Finished                     Left Distance {:>4.0f}     Right Distance {:>4.0f}'.format(Iteration, DistanceL, DistanceR)
        Ending = '        LeftPower {:>5.0f}    RightPower {:>5.0f}'.format(
            LeftPower, RightPower)
        print(Beginning, Ending)
        Sound.beep()

        Beginning = '{:3d}    Target {:3.0f}    Distance {:>4.0f}'.format(Iteration, Target, Distance)
        Ending = '    Delta {:>4.0f}    Integral {:>5.0f}    Derivative {:>5.0f}    LastError {:>5.0f}    PID {:>5.0f}    SpeedFactor {:>5.0f}    LeftPower {:>5.0f}    RightPower {:>5.0f}'.format(
            Error, Integral, Derivative, LastError, PID, SpeedFactor, LeftPower, RightPower)
        print(Beginning, Ending)
        sleep(DelayTime)

        while not ts.value():  # Stop program by pressing touch sensor button
                # Infrared sensor in proximity mode will measure distance to the closest
                # object in front of it.

#                    Sound.speak('FORWARD')
                    sleep(DelayTime)
                    Iteration += 1
                    Distance = ir.value()
                    if Distance < Target:
#                        print('in Distance < Target loop')
                        Leds.set_color(Leds.LEFT, Leds.RED)
                        Leds.set_color(Leds.RIGHT, Leds.GREEN)

#                        Sound.speak('RIGHT')
                        sleep(DelayTime)
                    else:
#                        print('Close else')
                        Leds.set_color(Leds.LEFT, Leds.GREEN)
                        Leds.set_color(Leds.RIGHT, Leds.RED)

#                        Sound.speak('LEFT')
                        sleep(DelayTime)

                    Error = Target - Distance
                    Integral += Error
                    Derivative = Error - LastError

                    if Integral < -MaxTurnPower:
                        Integral = -MaxTurnPower
                    if Integral > MaxTurnPower:
                        Integral = MaxTurnPower

                    if Derivative < -MaxTurnPower:
                        Derivative = -MaxTurnPower
                    if Derivative > MaxTurnPower:
                        Derivatine = MaxTurnPower

                    PID = Kp * Error + Ki * Integral + Kd * Derivative

                    if PID < -MaxTurnPower:
                        PID = -MaxTurnPower
                    if PID > MaxTurnPower:
                        PID = MaxTurnPower

                    LeftPower = SpeedFactor + PID
                    RightPower = SpeedFactor - PID

                    if LeftPower < -900:
                        LeftPower = -901
                    if LeftPower > 900:
                        LeftPower = 902

                    if RightPower < -900:
                        RightPower = -903
                    if RightPower > 900:
                        RightPower = 904

                    Beginning = '{:3d}    Target {:3.0f}    Distance {:>4.0f}'.format(Iteration, Target, Distance)
                    Ending = '    Delta {:>4.0f}    Integral {:>5.0f}    Derivative {:>5.0f}    LastError {:>5.0f}    PID {:>5.0f}    SpeedFactor {:>5.0f}    LeftPower {:>5.0f}    RightPower {:>5.0f}'.format(
                        Error, Integral, Derivative, LastError, PID, SpeedFactor, LeftPower, RightPower)

                    print(Beginning, Ending)
                    LeftWheel.run_timed(time_sp=Time, speed_sp=LeftPower)
                    RightWheel.run_timed(time_sp=Time, speed_sp=RightPower)

                    LastError = Error

#    Leds.set_color(Leds.UP, Leds.RED)
#    Leds.set_color(Leds.DOWN, Leds.RED)
    Leds.set_color(Leds.LEFT, Leds.RED)
    Leds.set_color(Leds.RIGHT, Leds.RED)
    LeftWheel.run_to_rel_pos(position_sp=-20, speed_sp=900, stop_action="hold")
    RightWheel.run_to_rel_pos(position_sp=-400, speed_sp=900, stop_action="hold")
    Sound.beep()
```

Comment: That is a great picture of a great EV3-G program written in a great programming  language editor.  I do not understand how your EV3-G editor in 2014 is better than my editor in 2017.  Is it possible that you are using the Macintosh software.

Comment: That is a great picture of a great EV3-G program written in a great programming  language editor.  I do not understand how your EV3-G editor in 2014 is better than my editor in 2017.  Is it possible that you are using the Macintosh software.      Specifically, when you break your code into rows, your wires are equally spaced between the rows.  My editor temporarily does that, but when the last end is anchored, the equal spacing is lost.  My EV3-G editor is up to date for 2017.  What am I missing?

Comment: "your EV3-G editor in 2014 is better than my editor in 2017" - it was written on a PC using the "education" version of EV3-G.  That version has comment blocks, which allow adding comments that travel with the linked blocks. It's available from the "Advanced" tab.  Either version is a free download. The image PID is known to work on the NXT brick, but not EV3. EV3 handles the loops too fast and needs to add a delay before re-entering the loop.